# How to access results from BestExporter while using train_and_evaluate?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

When I use `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate` with a `BestExporter` in my `EvalSpec` the return value at the end might not include an `export_result` since the final evaluation call won't necessarily lead to an export. This happens for instance if your last checkpoint doesn't lead to a lower loss on your evaluation set.

How do you access the last `export_result` that led to an export from the `BestExporter`? Ideally I would like to have a `list` of each `(metrics, export_results)` at the end of `train_and_evaluate` instead of just the last one.

---

For anyone desperate for a workaround you can access the directory using python built-ins like this.

```py
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(...)
best_exporter = tf.estimator.BestExporter(...)

# Add best_exporter to your eval_spec
# Make train_spec
metrics, export_results = tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(...)

best_export_dir = os.path.join(estimator.model_dir, 'export', best_exporter.name)
savedmodels = os.listdir(best_export_dir)
best_model = savedmodels[-1]
```

Obviously a better method would be preferred. The particular issue I'm describing here is that `export_results` might just be `[None]` since the last checkpoint didn't result in an export even when there has been an earlier export.

---

For anyone who cares these are the relevant bits of code from tensorflow r1.13 tracing the life of `export_results` from call to value,

[tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/r1.13/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py#L471) 471

[_TrainingExecutor.run](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/r1.13/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py#L611) 611

[_TrainingExecutor.run_local](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/r1.13/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py#L703) 703

[_NewCheckpointListenerForEvaluate.after_save](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/r1.13/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py#L517) 517

[_NewCheckpointListenerForEvaluate._evaluate](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/r1.13/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py#L536) 536

[_Evaluator.evaluate_and_export](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/r1.13/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py#L924) 924

[_Evaluator._export_eval_result](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/r1.13/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py#L948) 948

Comment: Great question, I just found BestExporter as a solution to one of my problems, but I simply cannot get some dict-like structure giving me the evaluation metrics for each of the exported results.

If you are not bound to Estimators, consider looking at TF2 where they deal with this in a better way using the Keras API.

Answer (score 0):

I might have found a solution if you are willing to (slightly) change the source code, specifically the `_SavedModelExporter` class implementation, in `tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\exporter.py`.

First, I am using the package `tensorflow_estimator`, instead of getting `estimator` from `tf.estimator`. If the solution doesn't work in your case, consider using `tensorflow_estimator` - you should not lose anything by that.

Basically, `_SavedModelExporter` has a method called `export`, which, in my case (tensorflow 1.13.2, tensorflow_estimator 1.13.0), starts in line 116 and has the following implementation:

```
  def export(self, estimator, export_path, checkpoint_path, eval_result,
             is_the_final_export):
    del is_the_final_export

    export_result = estimator.export_savedmodel(
        export_path,
        self._serving_input_receiver_fn,
        assets_extra=self._assets_extra,
        as_text=self._as_text,
        checkpoint_path=checkpoint_path,
        strip_default_attrs=self._strip_default_attrs)

################
###I ADDED THIS
################
    results_file = os.path.join(export_result, b"model_eval.txt")
    with open(results_file, mode="w") as f:
      for result in eval_result:
        f.write(result + ": " + str(eval_result[result]) + "\n")
################
###END OF I ADDED THIS
################
    return export_result
```

In the code above, as marked, I added code which loops through the dictionary of evaluation results (`eval_result` variable, already available for us but not used here!) and saves it as lines to a file. This file will be saved inside the same folder which contains the exported model, that is, something like `export\best_exporter\1565348723\`.

Some points:

1) You asked for a returned value, and I am not giving you that. I am instead saving it to file, since I think this is the solution with least changes to the source code. Do let me know if you cannot work with that.

2) You can develop on this solution. For example, you can probably save all entries to the same file instead of saving one file per exported model.

3) All three implemented exporters (`LatestExporter`, `FinalExporter` and `BestExporter`) are making calls to `_SavedModelExporter`, which we just changed. So you can either live with this behavior for all different Exporters, or have some variable, default to `False`, which controls whether the saving to file will happen or not. Then, expose this variable through the call to BestExporter.

Hope I could help with something.